# Environmental variables in login shells and interactive shells

Tags: bash, ssh, shell, ubuntu-12.04, environment-variables

I'm sort of confused of login shells and interactive shells.

If I run

```
ssh my_remote_server 'echo $HOME'
```

I can get

```
/home/shawk
```

But when I run

```
ssh my_remote_server 'echo $ANOTHER_VAR'
```

I got a blank line.

`export ANOTHER_VAR=$HOME/tr` is set in both `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` on `my_remote_server`. So the question is, where should I set this variable? `my_remote_server` runs Ubuntu 12.04 btw.

Comment: Do you mean it is exported in your _local_ `.bashrc` or the one on the server you are connecting to?

Comment: @terdon on the server I'm connecting to

Comment: Hang on, are you setting it with the dollar sign? I mean do you have `$ANOTHER_VAR=$HOME/tr` in your `.bashrc` or `ANOTHER_VAR=$HOME/tr`?

Comment: @terdon sorry another typo :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that variables are expanded in double quotes by the shell. It means the local value of the variable is printed. To get the remote variable, you have to use single quotes or backslash the dollar sign:

```
ssh remote_server 'echo $ANOTHER_VAR'
```